# How to get linux console $COLUMNS and $ROWS from PHP cli?

Tags: php, linux, bash, command-line, command-line-interface

I'm currently creating a new neat CLI library for PHP, and i'd like to figure out the width/height of the console it's running in.

I've tried many things like digging through $_ENV, exec("echo $COLUMNS"), etc, but no result, while if i type echo $COLUMNS or $ROWS in bash commandline, it neatly displays the value.

What do i need to do to access this value from PHP?

I'm using .sh scripts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

require_once('lib.commandline.php');


class HelloWorld extends CommandLineApp {

  public function main($args) {

       echo('O, Hai.');

    }

}
```

**Update**
Final solution:

```
public function getScreenSize() { 
      preg_match_all("/rows.([0-9]+);.columns.([0-9]+);/", strtolower(exec('stty -a |grep columns')), $output);
      if(sizeof($output) == 3) {
        $this->settings['screen']['width'] = $output[1][0];
        $this->settings['screen']['height'] = $output[2][0];
      }
    }
```

Comment: So uh.. I realize it's been close to 10 years, but you still got that CLI lib? Github? :-)

Comment: @MSpreij [Here's his GitHub](https://github.com/SchizoDuckie?tab=repositories&language=php). I couldn't find anything btw

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Another shell option that requires no parsing is `tput`:

```
$this->settings['screen']['width'] = exec('tput cols')
$this->settings['screen']['height'] = exec('tput lines')
```

Comment: excellent. I totally forgot about `tput` while digging for how to get just that info from `stty`.

Comment: Super! Very useful and gentle reminder about how elegant solution can be.

Comment: This solution even works on Windows if you install Git for windows. The alternative is to parse `mode con /status`.

Comment: As a note: the value returned by tput will not update after resizing the window, but stty will

Comment: @pmiguelpinto: How so? It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Use the PHP [`ncurses_getmaxyx`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ncurses-getmaxyx.php) function.

```
ncurses_getmaxyx (STDSCR, $Height, $Width)
```

**PREVIOUSLY:**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

```
$cols = getenv('COLUMNS');
$rows = getenv('ROWS');
```

The "proper" way is probably to call the `TIOCGSIZE` ioctl to get the kernel's idea of the window size, or call the command `stty -a` and parse the results for `rows` and `columns`

Comment: Just want to say, COLUMNS & ROWS are not set in Terminal.app on Mac OS X. I've also had problems with those being inconsistent (for example, they worked in irb, but not when executing a ruby script, &c).

Comment: The environment variables are also not updated if the terminal is resized while your program is running.

Comment: Getenv doesn't work indeed, nor does $_ENV But thanks for the hint to stty -a, i'll parse that :)

Comment: I like the portability of my current solution :) Not all boxes have ncurses in PHP so i'd like it to be as bare as possible

Comment: given that you are the winner of this question, and that your top suggestion is currently an 'EXPERIMENTAL' function (their all-caps, not mine) could you take a moment and consolidate the various methods here, and show the actual right answer. Especially since you allude to the ioctl method as preferred method (without saying why its best), but you do not actually show how to do this. NOTE TO SELF: rather than complaining about this, wait six months and write a really good answer. Remember to thank Joe for writing an answer rather than just complianing...

Comment: The link in the answer is dead.

Answer (score 4):

I dunno, why one should ever need `grep` to parse `stty` output: it does have a separate option to report "the number of rows and columns according to the kernel".

One-liner, no error handling:

```
list($rows, $cols) = explode(' ', exec('stty size'));
```

One-liner, assume both rows/cols to be 0 in case of problems and suppress any error output:

```
list($rows, $cols) = explode(' ', @exec('stty size 2>/dev/null') ?: '0 0');
```

Answer (score 3):

`$COLUMNS` and `$LINES` is probably not being exported to your program. You can run `export LINES COLUMNS` before running your app, or you can get this information directly:

```
$fp=popen("resize", "r");
$b=stream_get_contents($fp);
preg_match("/COLUMNS=([0-9]+)/", $b, $matches);$columns = $matches[1];
preg_match("/LINES=([0-9]+)/", $b, $matches);$rows = $matches[1];
pclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

For the record, it is my function (PHP 7.2 and higher):

It works in Windows and Linux. In case of errors, it returns 80.

In the case of some wacky or too small value, it returns the minimum value (80)

ps: "mode con" does return the number of lines but it is based on the buffer than on the screen size.

ps2: Oddly but if I run it as a website, it returns 120 (Windows Host).

```php
   function calculateColSize($min=80) {
       try {
            if (PHP_OS_FAMILY === 'Windows') {
                $a1 = shell_exec('mode con');
                /*
                 * Estado para dispositivo CON:
                 * ----------------------------
                 * Líneas:              9001
                 * Columnas:            85
                 * Ritmo del teclado:   31
                 * Retardo del teclado: 1
                 * Página de códigos:    65001
                 */
                $arr = explode("\n", $a1);
                $col = trim(explode(':', $arr[4])[1]);

            } else {
                $col = exec('tput cols');
                /*
                 * 184
                 */
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $col = 80;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200122052321/http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) might be the answer, you could use the ANSI Escape codes to do that, by using the `echo` using the specific Escape code sequence, in particular the 'Query Device', which I found another link [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160402021521/http://www.it.usyd.edu.au/%7Etapted/ansi.html) that explains in detail. Perhaps using that might enable you to get the columns and rows of the screen...

Comment: This answer points to 2 links that are dead. Also, this answer doesn't explain how to get the console size after sending the escape sequence.

Answer (score -2):

Environment variables can be found in the $_ENV super global variable.

```
echo $_ENV['ROWS'];
```

for instance.

Comment: "I've tried many things like digging through $_ENV, exec("echo $COLUMNS"), etc, but no result", the poster mentioned.