# PHP Command Line Window Width

Tags: php, console, command-line-interface

In my php project I output several strings with long lengths. I want to cut these strings into pieces (All the same length) To format my output. In order to know how long these sections should be, I need to know the width of my ouput window. (CLI mode)

Is there any way I can detect the console width cross-platform?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
exec('mode con', $output);
```

Then parse what's returned.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [newt_get_screen_size](http://php.net/manual/en/function.newt-get-screen-size.php). This gives you the rows and columns (window width) of your terminal.

If you're on Linux/Unix only, you can also use [`stty -a`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty) and parse the output or use [`tput cols`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tput).

See also [How to get linux console $COLUMNS and $ROWS from PHP cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2203437/1741542).

Comment: This would work, but the machine I'm running on doesn't support NEWT.

Comment: @MaxSnijders I don't know, this is the only link I've found.

Comment: @MaxSnijders Please see updated answer, if you don't need to be cross platform.

Comment: ["This extension is not available for Windows platform"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/newt.installation.php).